# Summing Values from 2 data frames into one master dataframe in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I appreciate any help, even if it's a link to another question on stackoverflow!

I want to find the sum of the column called Customer in the first dataframe DF based off of the two dataframes below. I want it to match the Customer column in DF with DF_WK1 and find the sum of the values in column B and put it into the WK 1 column in the first dataframe DF.

My real limitation is I can't find anywhere on google where you can match a unique value from one dataframe to another and sum it up on there. I know how to hard code each one to get me the sum and I know how to make a dataframe with the unique values on it, but I need to make something that I can use everyweek that will have different values in the customer column.

df
(Master Customer list)

| Customer | WK1 |
| --- | --- |
| a | sum |
| b | sum |
| c | sum |
| d | sum |
| e | sum |
| f | sum |
| g | sum |
| h | sum |
| i | sum |
| j | sum |

DF_WK1

| Customer | price |
| --- | --- |
| a | 22 |
| b | 37 |
| c | 2 |
| a | 44 |
| e | 29 |
| c | 64 |
| i | 22 |
| j | 37 |
| h | 2 |
| a | 44 |
| e | 29 |
| c | 64 |

The code I'm working on right now is below. I know it's not nearly enough, but it does get me the sum that i need, it just doesn't fix my problem of having different customer names each week.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df= pd.read_excel("master_customer_list.xlsx")

DF_WK1 = pd.read_excel("test.xlsx")

#find the uniqe values

unique_values = df["CustomerName"].unique()

# Create a new dataframe with the unique values
df = pd.DataFrame(unique_values, columns=["CustomerName"]).reset_index()

# Print the new dataframe
print(df)

# Print the new dataframe
print(df)


#
df= DF_WK1.groupby(df.CustomerName)['price'].sum().reset_index()
```

Answer (score 3):

You likely want to combine the [`groupby.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html) and [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df['WK1'] = df['Customer'].map(DF_WK1.groupby('Customer')['price'].sum())
```

Comment: Thank you I solved it with the below code

Comment: import pandas as pd

# Load the data into Pandas dataframes
DF = pd.read_excel("Master_customer_list.xlsx")
DF_WK51 = pd.read_excel("WK51.xlsx")

# Left join the DF_WK1 dataframe to the DF dataframe on the "Customer" column
df = pd.merge(DF, DF_WK51[["Customer", "price"]], on="Customer", how="left")

# Group the data by "Customer" and calculate the sum of the "price" column
df = df.groupby("Customer")["price"].sum().reset_index()

# Rename the "price" column to "WK1"
df = df.rename(columns={"price": "WK1"})

# Print the resulting dataframe
print(df)